# Repair or rebuild Signal Interceptor after quest?

Tags: pc, fallout-4

Alright, ground rules: I'm on PC, so console commands are usable. However, no external save file editing or modding of the game files, if at all possible.

Is it possible to rebuild the parts or repair existing ones after the 'Molecular Level' quest? I just hate the old broken one you're left with, but kinda don't want to tear it down either. Anyone know of any ways to fix it or or replace it using the console, or by glitching the game in any way?

Comment: Have you tried to repair it in "workshop mode"? I remember when i focused it in workshop mode it gave me the option to repair, but I didn't. Will test this today.

Comment: I checked it, seems like you can't repair it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'saq' console command, **s**tart **a**ll **q**uests, then use 'caqs', **c**omplete **a**ll **q**uest **s**tages once you have finished with it. Keep in mind that you will receive all quest XP and items at the same time, so there may be a little lag spike.